# Display truncated text on div hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is a basic question. I have a div with some text in it. When that text is long, it's getting truncated as I have set overflow hidden. I want to show that complete text when you hover over that div. I know for an image I can set alt tag, but how do I do it for div

Comment: not quite sure is it what you need (hint) `<div title="long text here">short text</div>`

Comment: `title` will work but with no code example im not sure if this is the right way for him

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski But I don't think there's any "short text". The innerHTML holds the full content, but it's "hidden" because of a style. It's not like it's truly truncated

Comment: Yes with title it looks exactly the way I wanted, hope that effect is same across all the browsers.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj just out of curiosity, why do you think it's not the right way? I didn't quite get your comment.

Comment: Semantically the `title` attribute provides advisory information about the content of the tag it is attached to. I dont think that putting the full content of an element there is semantically correct. Look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set the overflow to visible on hover so the text would then be visible.

CSS:

```
#your_div_id:hover{
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work, but I'm looking for more like image alt tag effect

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can do this:

HTML

```
<div> Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
  width: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
$('div').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css("overflow", "visible");
});

$('div').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvHtE/)

Comment: How would you use a tooltip instead?